# URL Handlers Multiple Dir

Tags: google-app-engine

```
File Structure

 ROOT
    - app.yaml
    - flashfolder/bin-release
                  -sfx
                  -maps
                  -resources
```

I've tried,

```
- url: /flashFolder/bin-release/*(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml|tmx|mp3))
  static_dir: \1
  upload: static/flashFolder/bin-release/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml|tmx|mp3))

- url: /flashFolder/bin-release/*(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml|tmx|mp3))
  static_files: \1
  upload: static/flashFolder/bin-release/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml|tmx|mp3))

- url: /flashFolder/bin-release/
  static_dir: \1
```

Anybody have a link explaining the the URL handlers, other than what Google provides, the python goes right over my head.

I just wanna upload all the folders within bin-release and their contents without having to specifically map them. Is there a wild card I can throw within the bin-release map?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
- url: /flashFolder/bin-release/
  static_dir: flashFolder/bin-release/
```

unless you really need to filter based on the file extension